# RecyclerView does not initialize all objects

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `Recyclerview` that contains 26 objects. When it starts, it draws 14 objects, and when you scroll to the bottom, it draws the remaining 12. The problem is that if you don't scroll to the bottom and click the `cvAccept` button, it will throw an error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property colorItemLight has not been initialized
at com.multi_theme_3.Adapter.AdapterEditCustomColor.onBindViewHolder$lambda$1(AdapterEditCustomColor.kt:252)
```

That is, everything that is located further than `property colorItemLight` is not initialized, and this causes an error.

I don’t quite understand how to fix this, do I need to make sure that when `Recyclerview` starts, it draws all 26 objects at once?

My Adapter

```
class AdapterEditCustomColor(private val context: Context, private val itemColor: List<ItemPalette>, val p: Int?, var cvAccept: CardView) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterEditCustomColor.VH>() {

    private lateinit var colorBackgroundMain: String

    private lateinit var colorBackgroundSecondLight: String
    private lateinit var colorBackgroundSecondDark: String

    private lateinit var colorBackgroundThirdLight: String
    private lateinit var colorBackgroundThirdDark: String

    private lateinit var colorAppBar: String
    private lateinit var colorStatusBar: String
    private lateinit var colorNavigationBar: String

    private lateinit var colorTextMainLight: String
    private lateinit var colorTextSubLight: String

    private lateinit var colorTextMainDark: String
    private lateinit var colorTextSubDark: String

    private lateinit var colorNoActiveLight: String
    private lateinit var colorNoActiveDark: String

    private lateinit var colorItemLight: String
    private lateinit var colorItemDark: String
    private lateinit var colorItem: String
    private lateinit var colorDarken: String

    private lateinit var colorAccentTextMain: String
    private lateinit var colorAccentTextSecond: String
    private lateinit var colorAccentTextThird: String

    private lateinit var colorAccentTextNoActiveDark: String

    private lateinit var colorAccentBackgroundMain: String
    private lateinit var colorAccentBackgroundSecond: String
    private lateinit var colorAccentBackgroundThird: String
    private lateinit var colorAccentItem: String

    inner class VH(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val cv1: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cv1)
        val cv2: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cv2)
        val tv1: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv1)
        val tv2: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv2)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
        return VH(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_pallete, parent, false))
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        val item = itemColor[position]

        val gspStandardAndroidTheme = context.getSharedPreferences("nameStandardAndroidTheme", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val statusSAT: Boolean = gspStandardAndroidTheme.getBoolean("keyStandardAndroidTheme", false)
        if (statusSAT) {

            holder.cv2.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ThemeActivity.colorBackgroundThirdDark))
            holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(ThemeActivity.colorTextMainLight))
            holder.tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(ThemeActivity.colorTextSubLight))
        }

        try {
            holder.cv1.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item.colorId))
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            holder.cv1.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }

        holder.tv1.text = item.colorName
        holder.tv2.text = item.colorId

        if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundMain") colorBackgroundMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundSecondLight") colorBackgroundSecondLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundSecondDark") colorBackgroundSecondDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundThirdLight") colorBackgroundThirdLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundThirdDark") colorBackgroundThirdDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorAppBar") colorAppBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorStatusBar") colorStatusBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorNavigationBar") colorNavigationBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorTextMainLight") colorTextMainLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorTextSubLight") colorTextSubLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorTextMainDark") colorTextMainDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorTextSubDark") colorTextSubDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorNoActiveLight") colorNoActiveLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorNoActiveDark") colorNoActiveDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorItemLight") colorItemLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorItemDark") colorItemDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorItem") colorItem = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorDarken") colorDarken = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextMain") colorAccentTextMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextSecond") colorAccentTextSecond = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextThird") colorAccentTextThird = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextNoActiveDark") colorAccentTextNoActiveDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundMain") colorAccentBackgroundMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundSecond") colorAccentBackgroundSecond = holder.tv2.text.toString()
        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundThird") colorAccentBackgroundThird = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        if (item.colorName == "colorAccentItem") colorAccentItem = holder.tv2.text.toString()

        holder.cv2.setOnClickListener {
            val dialogEditCustomColor: DialogEditCustomColor = DialogEditCustomColor.newInstance()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("colorName", item.colorName)
            bundle.putString("colorId", holder.tv2.text as String)
            bundle.putInt("colorPosition", p!!)
            dialogEditCustomColor.arguments = bundle
            dialogEditCustomColor.show((context as ActivityMain).supportFragmentManager, "dialogEditCustomColor")

            if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundMain") colorBackgroundMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundSecondLight") colorBackgroundSecondLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundSecondDark") colorBackgroundSecondDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundThirdLight") colorBackgroundThirdLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundThirdDark") colorBackgroundThirdDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorAppBar") colorAppBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorStatusBar") colorStatusBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorNavigationBar") colorNavigationBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorTextMainLight") colorTextMainLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorTextSubLight") colorTextSubLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorTextMainDark") colorTextMainDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorTextSubDark") colorTextSubDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorNoActiveLight") colorNoActiveLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorNoActiveDark") colorNoActiveDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorItemLight") colorItemLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorItemDark") colorItemDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorItem") colorItem = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorDarken") colorDarken = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextMain") colorAccentTextMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextSecond") colorAccentTextSecond = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextThird") colorAccentTextThird = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextNoActiveDark") colorAccentTextNoActiveDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundMain") colorAccentBackgroundMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundSecond") colorAccentBackgroundSecond = holder.tv2.text.toString()
            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundThird") colorAccentBackgroundThird = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            if (item.colorName == "colorAccentItem") colorAccentItem = holder.tv2.text.toString()

            dialogEditCustomColor.setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { key, bundleResult ->
                if (key == "requestKey") {
                    holder.tv2.text = bundleResult.getString("et").toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundMain") colorBackgroundMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundSecondLight") colorBackgroundSecondLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundSecondDark") colorBackgroundSecondDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundThirdLight") colorBackgroundThirdLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorBackgroundThirdDark") colorBackgroundThirdDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorAppBar") colorAppBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorStatusBar") colorStatusBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorNavigationBar") colorNavigationBar = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorTextMainLight") colorTextMainLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorTextSubLight") colorTextSubLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorTextMainDark") colorTextMainDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorTextSubDark") colorTextSubDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorNoActiveLight") colorNoActiveLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorNoActiveDark") colorNoActiveDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorItemLight") colorItemLight = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorItemDark") colorItemDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorItem") colorItem = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorDarken") colorDarken = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextMain") colorAccentTextMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextSecond") colorAccentTextSecond = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextThird") colorAccentTextThird = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentTextNoActiveDark") colorAccentTextNoActiveDark = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundMain") colorAccentBackgroundMain = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundSecond") colorAccentBackgroundSecond = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentBackgroundThird") colorAccentBackgroundThird = holder.tv2.text.toString()

                    if (item.colorName == "colorAccentItem") colorAccentItem = holder.tv2.text.toString()
                }
            }
        }

        cvAccept.setOnClickListener {

            val gspeCustomColor = context.getSharedPreferences("nameColor", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorBackgroundMain", colorBackgroundMain)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorBackgroundSecondLight", colorBackgroundSecondLight)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorBackgroundSecondDark", colorBackgroundSecondDark)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorBackgroundThirdLight", colorBackgroundThirdLight)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorBackgroundThirdDark", colorBackgroundThirdDark)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAppBar", colorAppBar)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorStatusBar", colorStatusBar)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorNavigationBar", colorNavigationBar)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorTextMainLight", colorTextMainLight)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorTextSubLight", colorTextSubLight)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorTextMainDark", colorTextMainDark)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorTextSubDark", colorTextSubDark)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorNoActiveLight", colorNoActiveLight)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorNoActiveDark", colorNoActiveDark)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorItemLight", colorItemLight)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorItemDark", colorItemDark)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorItem", colorItem)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorDarken", colorDarken)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentTextMain", colorAccentTextMain)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentTextSecond", colorAccentTextSecond)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentTextThird", colorAccentTextThird)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentTextNoActiveDark", colorAccentTextNoActiveDark)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentBackgroundMain", colorAccentBackgroundMain)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentBackgroundSecond", colorAccentBackgroundSecond)
            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentBackgroundThird", colorAccentBackgroundThird)

            gspeCustomColor.putString("colorAccentItem", colorAccentItem)

            gspeCustomColor.apply()

            ContextUtils.getActivity(context)!!.recreate()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemColor.size
}
```

I tried this:

```
rvPalette.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
rvPalette.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH)
rvPalette.setItemViewCacheSize(26)
```

But it didn't work.

ItemPalette:

```
class ItemPalette(
    val colorName: String,
    val colorId: String,
    var colorPosition: Int
)

    private fun pallete() {

        val contacts = mutableListOf<ItemPalette>()

        val gspStandardAndroidTheme = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("nameStandardAndroidTheme", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val keyStandardAndroidTheme: Boolean = gspStandardAndroidTheme.getBoolean("keyStandardAndroidTheme", false)

        if (keyStandardAndroidTheme) {

            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundMain", ThemeActivity.colorBackgroundMain,2))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundSecondLight", ThemeActivity.colorBackgroundSecondLight,3))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundSecondDark", ThemeActivity.colorBackgroundSecondDark,4))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundThirdLight", ThemeActivity.colorBackgroundThirdLight,5))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundThirdDark", ThemeActivity.colorBackgroundThirdDark,6))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAppBar", ThemeActivity.colorAppBar,7))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorStatusBar", ThemeActivity.colorStatusBar,8))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorNavigationBar", ThemeActivity.colorNavigationBar,9))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextMainLight", ThemeActivity.colorTextMainLight,10))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextSubLight", ThemeActivity.colorTextSubLight,11))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextMainDark", ThemeActivity.colorTextMainDark,12))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextSubDark", ThemeActivity.colorTextSubDark,13))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorNoActiveLight", ThemeActivity.colorNoActiveLight,14))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorNoActiveDark", ThemeActivity.colorNoActiveDark,15))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorItemLight", ThemeActivity.colorItemLight,16))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorItemDark", ThemeActivity.colorItemDark,17))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorItem", ThemeActivity.colorItem,18))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorDarken", ThemeActivity.colorDarken,19))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextMain", ThemeActivity.colorAccentTextMain,20))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextSecond", ThemeActivity.colorAccentTextSecond,21))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextThird", ThemeActivity.colorAccentTextThird,22))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextNoActiveDark", ThemeActivity.colorAccentTextNoActiveDark,23))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentBackgroundMain", ThemeActivity.colorAccentBackgroundMain,24))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentBackgroundSecond", ThemeActivity.colorAccentBackgroundSecond,25))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentBackgroundThird", ThemeActivity.colorAccentBackgroundThird,26))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentItem", ThemeActivity.colorAccentItem,27))
        } else {
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundMain", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorBackgroundMain),2))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundSecondLight", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorBackgroundSecondLight),3))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundSecondDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorBackgroundSecondDark),4))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundThirdLight", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorBackgroundThirdLight),5))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorBackgroundThirdDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorBackgroundThirdDark),6))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAppBar", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAppBar),7))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorStatusBar", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorStatusBar),8))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorNavigationBar", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorNavigationBar),9))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextMainLight", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorTextMainLight),10))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextSubLight", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorTextSubLight),11))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextMainDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorTextMainDark),12))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorTextSubDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorTextSubDark),13))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorNoActiveLight", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorNoActiveLight),14))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorNoActiveDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorNoActiveDark),15))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorItemLight", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorItemLight),16))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorItemDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorItemDark),17))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorItem", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorItem),18))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorDarken", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorDarken),19))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextMain", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentTextMain),20))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextSecond", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentTextSecond),21))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextThird", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentTextThird),22))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentTextNoActiveDark", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentTextNoActiveDark),23))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentBackgroundMain", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentBackgroundMain),24))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentBackgroundSecond", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentBackgroundSecond),25))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentBackgroundThird", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentBackgroundThird),26))
            contacts.add(ItemPalette("colorAccentItem", getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorAccentItem),27))
        }

        val position: Int = requireArguments().getInt("position")

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        adapter = AdapterAddCustomColor(requireContext(), contacts, cvAccept, position)
        rvPalette.adapter = adapter
        rvPalette.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rvPalette.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvPalette.itemAnimator?.changeDuration = 0
    }
```

Comment: as far as I understand problem arise because you initializing values in `if` condition, so when if condition gets false your object don't initialize. so make sure you put else block too to initialize it with other values or check if object initialize before using it,

Comment: @Iftekhar The problem is not in the `if` condition, because if you scroll the `RecyclerView` to the bottom, everything works.

Comment: please share values of `List<ItemPalette>`

Comment: @Iftekhar I added it to the question

Comment: list values also

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture is broken.

You have declared member variables in your adapter that will not get initialized until the user has scrolled through all your data. This makes no sense. You should store the current values of your 26 properties in shared preferences or some other location (memory storage, database, whatever). Then your adapter can show the current values in the recycler view and if the user wants to change a value, you need to change the value in the shared preferences or other storage.